# deploying java web application having huge class file

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I have a JSP/Servlet web application deployed in Glassfish which is having a number of Servlets and huge class files. When I make even minor changes in the Servlet or class file, then the *whole* web application gets re-deployed which takes considerable amount of time. Not only that, all the JSPs and Servlets are unloaded from memory and upon being called it takes around 1 second for getting initialized.

This problem does not occur when I change code of JSP, JS or CSS files as only that particular file is re-deployed.

Can I do anything so that the Servlets or those huge class files deployed separately and thus not the whole web application?

Comment: open a netbeans issue.  be prepared to attach a project that will help them replicate the issue.

Comment: @vkraemer ok i do that... but ran i into your profile and saw that you work on glassfish and you are least bothered about opening a issue?? why?? or you not interested in netbeans??

Comment: is this is a glassfish issue too that app has to redeployed upon class change?? should i open a glassfish issue too??

Comment: Regarding why didn't I open an issue for you?  Because I cannot fill in the details necessary to actually make progress on the issue that YOU are having.  I may run into something SIMILAR and resolve that... but your issue would remain unresolved.  While I would be spending time fixing something, I would not be addressing your issue. Regarding opening a GF issue... no. just open an NB issue and provide details. I will file issues with other GF developers as I identify issues that they can reproduce and resolve.

Comment: I have post a bug on netbeans bugzilla... hope you contribute so that may be jsp/servlets containers can be done better in future...

Comment: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194121

Answer (score 1):

When you say "huge", do you mean "I have a small number of .class files, but their sizes are very large" or "I have a large number of small to modest-sized .class files"?

If it's the former, you should be worried about the size of the .class files.

Perhaps there's a hot deploy feature that you can take advantage of if you deploy an exploded view of the WAR file.

"...upon being called it takes around 1 second for getting initialized...." - are you really complaining about a 1 second redeploy time?

Comment: I don't know, I use IntelliJ.  If you see it being redeployed on save, then the answer is "yes" - believe the evidence you see with your own eyes.  Is that too slow?